# What is the impact of a good support in a Ranked Solo Queue game?

Tags: league-of-legends

People keep telling me never to support in Solo Queue, but others tell me that if you're amazing at it, you can carry just as hard.

Which one is it?

Answer (score 2):

It is true that you can win a game as a carry easier than you can as a support, but your team might get screwed over if the enemy team has a support and good carries while your team just has squishy carries. The support's role is to make sure that at least one of the carries gets fed enough to win the game for the team. That isn't to say that a team with no support character will always lose, but they may have done better with a support.

Comment: my my, you've rushed ahead of me ace, 59 more than me.

Answer (score 1):

Ranked Solo Queue is a real pain for support. Even if you're good at it, it's not really obvious that you'll get in sync with the carry. To be really efficient in ranked game, you need a sufficiently reliable carry. There you can make a difference because you'll get him fed, get him kills and farms, saving his life multiple times. There is the true support strength.

Compared to the same carry with a bad support, you'll win. But don't get wrong, you won't carry the game. Your carry will do it for you. You play support or you play carry.

The real pain in ranked game is that you will probably get matched with bad team-mates (at least at start) that do not get the real principle of what a support is and are just hoping to have a mobile health pot at their side. They are hardest carry to support, because they don't know your strength or weaknesses and will fail by assuming too much and not taking you into account whether it be mana, cool-down etc. ("Where is my heal, where is my shield, why no ult?")

The best experience I had in ranked game as support is with a duo partner that can carry for me. Sometimes works too with a duo in another lane, or jungling, because you still can synergise during mid-game, ganks and team-fights.

But still, support are the key of many games, but games where people know to play their champion and their role. Bad carries makes bad supports.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a support main. I have however taken to enjoying playing the role when i don't feel confident in a different role or when I am last pick.
Now to answer your question a good support WILL carry both bot lane and mid lane. That and a compitent jungler means you will have a lot of control over the bot side of the map. Now this is in ideal situations as this is league not everything will go as it should so even if you do well as support if your team is struggling you will not enjoy being support.

So that is the impact of a good support. Now I will not say how as every game is different put enough pressure bot lane and mid lane will probably want to help put enough pressure mid lane and your mid lane will want to help you. I generally look at how the lane is going can I kill them if i can i stay bot lane if i can't I look at my adc, can she get farm without dying if its a yes then I wait for level 3-4 and roam mid ask the jungler to show up and it usually nets a kill or shoves the guy out so mids open what do we do. Look at the wave can you push it to the turret yes ok if you can not roam bot as four and they will back out and thats bot side enemy jungle if your jungler a devourer jungler yes ok then let him take a camp then do dragon..... I can go on forever its all situationaly you have to look at everything given to you and make these calls. they may not be the right calls sometimes but if you team responds and you do it as a team then it just helps your whole team out later on as they will work with you.

SO yep thats How I have seen support working out in soloq for me. I mostly play thresh which is why I roam a lot even on janna I will roam but not as much as I do with thresh you just have to ask yourself what can I do and what can we get from it we being your team. Every chance you get just ask yourself that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different kinds of Support champions, and it's important to know the difference when you're determining your "carry" potential in a game.

First things first; typically the support is a playmaker of some kind. Whether it's landing the root with Soraka E, or pulling the full E>Q>W combo off with Leona, you're setting up a play for your team to follow up on.

### **Lane Types**

### *Sustain*

Sustain lanes are facilitated by champs with a heal or shield that can target their carry. These lanes counter the **Poke** lane type. Example champions are Sona, Soraka, and Nami.

### *Poke*

Poke lanes are facilitated by champs with some kind of reliable, long-range damaging ability. These lanes counter the **Bully** lane type. Example champions are Janna, Lulu, and Thresh.

### *Bully*

Bully lanes are facilitated by champs with high base stats and good hp/armor scaling. They also usually have a lot of methods for locking down opponents. These lanes counter the **Sustain** lane type. Example champions are Leona, Braum, and Alistar.

---

As you can see, there is some semblance of Rock, Paper, Scissors here, but it is important to note that the carry selected affects the dynamic of the lane. If you have a Caitlyn, you should probably play a bit more reactive, even if you picked Leona. If you have a Graves, you should probably play forward a bit more, even if you picked Sona.

---

### About Carrying Games

It's important to understand your kit and the kits of your opponents when determining your carry potential for a game.

For example, if your opponents are running a gap-closing, death-ball type team composition (Yasuo, Shyvana, Malphite, Diana, Lissandra, etc), you know that disengage or counter-engage are going to be what makes you a potential carry. For that type of composition, you would probably want someone like Janna in order to disrupt all chase and engage. You could also choose Leona in order to counter-engage any fights.

This takes a very strong understanding of every champion's kit. You must understand what makes each champion strong, and what types of abilities neuter those strengths. Silence crushes those who rely on casting combos (this even applies to Bruiser-types that rely on using abilities like Rengar), knock-ups make initiation very difficult, suppress/stun completely eliminates the damage potential of an ADC for long periods of time, etc.

---

### Becoming a Carry

There are very few support class champions who have the potential to be an actual carry. The reason for this is that typically, support champions have skills with high base numbers, and low scaling in order to prevent them from being played in other lanes. There are exceptions to this, of course. Look for champions with a good variety of offensive and defensive abilities. Abilities that do both and scale well are even better. Champs like Lulu, Sona, and Nami all have the potential to deal a lot of damage while still fulfilling the support role.

Keep in mind that if you choose a support champion in the support role with the intent to carry, it means needing big, expensive items that will detract from the defensive support items you would typically have. If you go for this type of build, you must carry or risk a loss as a result of being less effective in the support role.

---

This is just my two cents after being a support main for a few seasons. I'm not particularly high-ranked, but I'm confident in my information.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the game and the support.

The short answer, though, is that you are not a carry. You can make plays, you can be the hero of a fight or game, but you are not usually a sustained (or even burst!) damage dealer. Most of your presence in the game is supposed to be to the benefit of other players. You are dependent on them, but your contributions should not be understated.

In general, as a support your job is to set up fights favorably for your teammates. This means keeping your team's vision up so your teammates don't get caught out of position, denying enemy vision so you can catch the enemy out of position, and helping to set fights up favorably--whether that means stunning the enemy team, cutting half of them off from the fight altogether, keeping the fed assassins off your ADC, or just landing the right Blitzcrank hook to end the fight before it starts.

So this means two things for a good support: first, if your team can follow up on your stuns and hooks, assuming your teammates didn't lose lane horribly, you will have a good shot at winning fights. Second, if your team *can't* follow up, your contributions won't mean much.

Basically good supports are a force multiplier on your team. They can't make plays from zero team potential, but they can turn strengths into very profitable opportunities.